# How to apply date now format in Create SubDirectory

Tags: c#

I want Date format as Folder Name(27-07-2010).. how to  Name it? I want to make it as my sub directory

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you looking for the line of code that will create a subdirectory (with a date) in C#, or looking for some other guidance?

Comment: yes.. Creating a Sub directory with date... lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the directory with `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` and you can specify the name with a date format string:

```
var dirName = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateTime dateTime;    
dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

**Update**

```
// The date you want for your folder. 
// Could be: DateTime.Now
DateTime dateTime; 

// The parent folder you want to create a subfolder in
// Could be: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for current dir
string parentFolder; 

Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(parentFolder, dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

Comment: Path Combine shows the error... not accepting second argument. It needs path

Comment: @Shiny: Not sure what you mean. I have tried this in a small test project and it worked.